# Amazon AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance - how to SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

New to Amazon AWS here. I setup a new ubuntu instance but cannot SSH to the instance. How do I find the login/password for SSH? I don't remember one being shared with me when I created that instance.

I added my IP to inbound traffic for the security group
I setup a key and am using the key with my Putty connection
I am able to get to the login step, but when I enter 'root' as the login (or any value), I get:

Server refused our key

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server send: publickey)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you deploy an EC2 instance in AWS, you'll be asked to select existing key-pair or create new one. if you choose to create new one, AWS will give you the keypair.
after new key-pair is downloaded, you need to change the key permission.
If you deploy an Ubuntu instance, the user usually `ubuntu`.
`ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@yourinstanceIP`
or you can select the instance, and you can click on `Connect` button.

Comment: Thank you - user 'ubuntu' was what I was looking for.